# Normal force at the bottom

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

> A solid sphere of mass $m$ is  released from rest from the rim of a hemispherical cup so that it rolls along the surface. If the rim of the the hemisphere is kept horizontal, find the normal force exerted by the cup on the ball when the ball reaches the bottom of the cup.

I can't understand why the normal force will be $$ mg + mv^2/(R-r)$$ Can someone  explain this with a free body diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre of the sphere is moving in a circle of radius R-r, as can be seen from a diagram very easily. Now, why we consider centre not any other point? The reason is that, first no other point on the sphere is moving in a circle. And secondly, Newton's laws for rigid body state that total force = mass * acceleration of centre of mass. Since centre of mass is moving in a circle, we can write the equation as $N-mg = \frac{mv^{2}}{R-r}$